# Error while parsing JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a JSON variable `json_text` and trying to create a list of change_requests but running into below error?can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this?

```
import sys,os,json
from collections import OrderedDict 
def main ():
    change_request_list=[]
    json_text=[OrderedDict([(u'branch', u'wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'change_request_list', [OrderedDict([(u'change_request', u'2028693'), (u'change_request_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)]))])]), (u'component', u'platform_vendor_qcom-proprietary_ship_wlan_common-tools_wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'description', u'cnss_diag: Capture PKTLOG by default to sdcard'), (u'gerrit', u'1892910'), (u'gerrit_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)])), (u'owner', u'c_rrajiv'), (u'project', u'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/wlan/common-tools'), (u'url', u'https://review-android.quicinc.com/#/c/1892910')]), OrderedDict([(u'branch', u'wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'change_request_list', [OrderedDict([(u'change_request', u'2029177'), (u'change_request_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)]))])]), (u'component', u'platform_vendor_qcom-proprietary_ship_wlan_common-tools_wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'description', u'pktlog: Close file decription before archiving and creating a new one'), (u'gerrit', u'1895098'), (u'gerrit_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)])), (u'owner', u'c_rrajiv'), (u'project', u'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/wlan/common-tools'), (u'url', u'https://review-android.quicinc.com/#/c/1895098')]), OrderedDict([(u'branch', u'wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'change_request_list', [OrderedDict([(u'change_request', u'2030712'), (u'change_request_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)]))])]), (u'component', u'platform_vendor_qcom-proprietary_ship_wlan_common-tools_wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'description', u'cnss_diag: Fix copyright header'), (u'gerrit', u'1897531'), (u'gerrit_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)])), (u'owner', u'c_rrajiv'), (u'project', u'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/wlan/common-tools'), (u'url', u'https://review-android.quicinc.com/#/c/1897531')]), OrderedDict([(u'branch', u'wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'change_request_list', [OrderedDict([(u'change_request', u'2032453'), (u'change_request_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)]))])]), (u'component', u'platform_vendor_qcom-proprietary_ship_wlan_common-tools_wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'description', u'cnss_diag: Printing newly backup packetlog file name.'), (u'gerrit', u'1905895'), (u'gerrit_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)])), (u'owner', u'c_rrajiv'), (u'project', u'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/wlan/common-tools'), (u'url', u'https://review-android.quicinc.com/#/c/1905895')]), OrderedDict([(u'branch', u'wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'change_request_list', [OrderedDict([(u'change_request', u'2033296'), (u'change_request_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)]))])]), (u'component', u'platform_vendor_qcom-proprietary_ship_wlan_common-tools_wlan-service.lnx.1.1-dev'), (u'description', u'cnss_diag: Configuration for disabling pkt logging on sdcard'), (u'gerrit', u'1905931'), (u'gerrit_approval_status', OrderedDict([(u'comment', None), (u'status', None)])), (u'owner', u'c_rrajiv'), (u'project', u'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/wlan/common-tools'), (u'url', u'https://review-android.quicinc.com/#/c/1905931')])]
    for cr in json_text:
        print cr
        change_request =  cr['change_request_list']['change_request']
        change_request_list.append(change_request)
    print change_request_list
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_parsing.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "json_parsing.py", line 8, in main
    change_request =  cr['change_request_list']['change_request']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `[0]` between the json key

```
for cr in json_text:
    print cr
    change_request =  cr['change_request_list'][0]['change_request']
    change_request_list.append(change_request)
print change_request_list
```